# How to use image files dynamically at runtime as button content in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resources

My current implementation loops through PNG files in a folder, and create a number of buttons with background images from the files in that folder.

For this to work, at design time in Visual Studio, I have to set the build action of every PNG in that folder to `resource`, and then use something as following

```cs
button.Content = new Image { 
             Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(product.ImageLink ?? "",UriKind.Relative)),
             Stretch = Stretch.Fill 
             }
```

The problem with this approach is that every time a new PNG file is added to the folder, I will need to set the build action of that PNG file to `resource` and re-publish the solution.

Is it instead possible to loop through all the PNG files at runtime  in a folder to use them as button content ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you actually try doing looping at runtime and setting the `button.Content`?

Comment: yeah i tried that, but just setting the button.Content doesnt work, the image has to be a resource for it to show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply enumerate the folder and add the file paths of interest to a `List` or `ObservableCollection` and bind it to a `ListBox` (or any `ItemsControl` of choice). Define a `DataTemplate` to render the image buttons. You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` to observe directories for changes.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private const string ImageFolderPath = @"C:\SomeImages";
  public ObservableCollection<string> ImageFilePaths { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

  private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ImageFilePaths.Clear();
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ImageFolderPath);
    var enumerationOptions = new EnumerationOptions();
    foreach (string imageFilePath in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", enumerationOptions)
      .Where(fileInfo => fileInfo.Extension is ".png" or ".jpg")
      .Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName))
    {
      this.ImageFilePaths.Add(imageFilePath);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Button Content="Load Images" 
          Click="OnClick" />
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=ImageFilePaths}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button>
          <Image Height="96"
                 Width="96"
                 Source="{Binding}" />
        </Button>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```